# Android Emulator on OSX 10.9 Not Starting

Tags: macos, android-emulator

I'm trying to start android emulator on my Macbook and been waiting to start for almost an hour. I've tried closing and re-starting. I've tried trying different memory options, but no luck.
I've found posts in this forum that say the emulator is slow, but is it slow like an hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured this out. Incase some one is wondering, it is nothing to do with mac or emulator.
When I installed the package from download, it came with a default Nexus 4 device. That device had this issue of starting (did not start at all).
I deleted that default device and created a new device, it starts. It is still slow as mentioned all over the web, but starts.